# Specifying Multiple Objects with jQuery Selector

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I have a navigation bar which consists of php-generated html as follows:

```
<ul>
<div class="container"><button type="button" name="1" class="delButton" alt="Delete"></button></div>
<a href="/" alt="Home">Home</a>
<div class="container"><button type="button" name="2" class="delButton" alt="Delete"></button></div>
<a href="/" alt="Events">Events</a>
<div class="container"><button type="button" name="3" class="delButton" alt="Delete"></button></div>
<a href="/" alt="Calendar">Calendar</a>
<div class="container"><button type="button" name="4" class="delButton" alt="Delete"></button></div>
<a href="/" alt="About Us">About Us</a>
</ul>
```

Each set consists of a delete button and a link. The name attribute of the button contains the unique id of the link following it, as per the mySQL database.

I'm using the following jQuery code to remove the link when its corresponding delete button is clicked. Note that I'm using a custom ajax() method, and not jQuery's ajax method.

```
$('.container button').click(function() {
     if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to remove this link?'))
        ajax('POST', '/deletelink.php', 'id='+this.name, function(xmlhttp) {
           $('.nav ul').load('/getnav.php');
        });
});
```

The above code works as expected when I click any one of the delete buttons, and it removes the corresponding link. However, if after deleting one link I try clicking on another delete button, nothing happens. The confirm() alert box doesn't even show up. This suggests that the click() function is not being entered for the second delete attempt.

My interpretation of this is that once the function executes the first time, it resolves the selector to that specific button that was clicked; meaning that subsequently clicking on a different '.container button' is going to have no effect in terms of this function.

Is my assessment correct? If so, is there any way to prevent the function from resolving the selector to the specific object? If not, are there any alternatives that allow me to use one function for all of the delete buttons I have setup now?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the exact question you posed, but in some cases it would be possible to simply delete the link with JQuery if the AJAX deletion request was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click handlers are overwritten when you load the `getnav.php` again. You can use the following construct:

```
$(document).on('click', '.container button', function() {
    // click handler code here
}
```

You should be able to narrow down the selectors as well:

```
$('.nav ul').on('click', '.container button', function() {
    // click handler code here
}
```

This binds the click handler on the `<ul>` itself and then uses the `.container button` selector to determine where to "send" the click event to.

See also: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: It should also be noted that `.on()` is _the_ best way to bind (for most intents and purposes).

Comment: What about using `$('.container button').live('click', function() {` seems simpler than .on()?

Comment: @Wolfram `.live()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to bind the event again, after loading the content after a delete. The best way to do it is use jQuery `on`. It will automatically find the new elements added to DOM that match your selector and bind them the event

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Use this instead

```
$('.nav ul').on('click', '.container button', function() {
```

Answer (score -1):

If the bar is PHP generated, you could always dump an onclick into the output during your loop. Something like:

```
onclick = "deleteLine('<?=$id?>'); void(0); return false;"
```

Then you could change your *.click* function to a function named deleteLine, such as:

```
function deleteLine(id) {
```

I realise it's not an amazing solution, but it should do the job.

Comment: There are several problems with this answer. First, it mixes the page's structure with Javascript in an unclean fashion. Second, the function name is vague. Third, the function is attached to an arbitrary context. Fourth, both "return false;" and "void(0);" are superfluous here. Fifth, this solution increases the information required from the response. Sixth, the question mark tags in your answer could be disabled on some PHP servers.

Comment: Hi Barbarrosa. Thanks for your feedback. Please note that the code was meant as a "proof of concept" rather than a recommended line of production code. I'll take what you said in mind though!